# How can I display the date in words like "February, Seventeenth 2016" using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have date `2016-02-17`, i was using `DATE_FORMAT('2016-02-17', '%M, %D %Y')` and display it like this `'february, 17th 2016'`, but i want to display `february, seventeenth 2016`, that is `17th` in word, please help me

Comment: @1000111, your comment makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry for that. Seeing the requirement first time I got frustrated a bit ( :() and couldn't help myself made a comment like that. @Rahul

Comment: @1000111, there is nothing wrong with the question as I see. You should rather consider deleting your comment since it doesn't help any much.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like that:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        MONTHNAME(NOW()),
        ',',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX('First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th 17th 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd 24th 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st', ' ' ,DAY(NOW())),
            ' ',
            - 1
        ),
        ' ',
        YEAR (NOW())
    );
```

**Note:** Replace `NOW()` by your date field and also update the text as you want inside the `SUBSTRING_INDEX('First Second....`.

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @sampleDate  := '2016-02-17';

SELECT
    CONCAT(
        MONTHNAME(@sampleDate),
        ', ',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX('First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th 17th 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd 24th 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st', ' ' ,DAY(@sampleDate)),
            ' ',
            - 1
        ),
        ' ',
        YEAR (@sampleDate)
    );
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/75524/1)</kbd>

Comment: Why str_to_date !?!

Comment: But it is not giving exact output, it is showing numeric value not in words

Comment: **But it is not giving exact output** Please can you be more specific? Share the output here. And like I said you need to change the text inside `SUBSTRING_INDEX` as you want `.....SUBSTRING_INDEX('First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th 17th 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd 24th 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st....` @bhanuavinash

Comment: No need to put the date inside `STR_TO_DATE`. Just being too painstaking @strawberry

Comment: I wrote like this 'SELECT
DATE_FORMAT('2016-02-17', '%M-%D-%Y') AS HIRED_DATE
FROM DUAL' and my output coming like this 'february, 17th-2016' but i want 'february, seventeenth-2016' that mean 17th is in words

Comment: It's too much obvious that you have tried yours not mine. Please try the query given in the answer and let me know. @bhanuavinash

Comment: Avinash maybe it's time for a little coffee break

Comment: Look there (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/75538/0). You need to change the text like `11th 12th 13th...` by your expected values. @bhanuavinash

Comment: Nice answer @1000111! Can you briefly explain why have you used '-1'...

Comment: I'll add explanation later. Busy right now :( .  Just for the time being: `The substring returned from right of the final delimiter when the specified number is a negative number.` @DhavalSimaria

Answer (score 0):

Write function and display the answer

```
function convert_number_to_words($number) {

$hyphen      = '-';
$conjunction = '  ';
$separator   = ' ';
$negative    = 'negative ';
$decimal     = ' point ';
$dictionary  = array(
    0                   => 'Zero',
    1                   => 'One',
    2                   => 'Two',
    3                   => 'Three',
    4                   => 'Four',
    5                   => 'Five',
    6                   => 'Six',
    7                   => 'Seven',
    8                   => 'Eight',
    9                   => 'Nine',
    10                  => 'Ten',
    11                  => 'Eleven',
    12                  => 'Twelve',
    13                  => 'Thirteen',
    14                  => 'Fourteen',
    15                  => 'Fifteen',
    16                  => 'Sixteen',
    17                  => 'Seventeen',
    18                  => 'Eighteen',
    19                  => 'Nineteen',
    20                  => 'Twenty',
    30                  => 'Thirty',
    40                  => 'Fourty',
    50                  => 'Fifty',
    60                  => 'Sixty',
    70                  => 'Seventy',
    80                  => 'Eighty',
    90                  => 'Ninety',
    100                 => 'Hundred',
    1000                => 'Thousand',
    1000000             => 'Million',
    1000000000          => 'Billion',
    1000000000000       => 'Trillion',
    1000000000000000    => 'Quadrillion',
    1000000000000000000 => 'Quintillion'
);

if (!is_numeric($number)) {
    return false;
}

if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
    // overflow
    trigger_error(
        'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
        E_USER_WARNING
    );
    return false;
}

if ($number < 0) {
    return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
}

$string = $fraction = null;

if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
    list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
}

switch (true) {
    case $number < 21:
        $string = $dictionary[$number];
        break;
    case $number < 100:
        $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
        $units  = $number % 10;
        $string = $dictionary[$tens];
        if ($units) {
            $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
        }
        break;
    case $number < 1000:
        $hundreds  = $number / 100;
        $remainder = $number % 100;
        $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
    default:
        $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
        $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
        $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
        $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
        if ($remainder) {
            $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
            $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
        }
        break;
}

if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
    $string .= $decimal;
    $words = array();
    foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
        $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
    }
    $string .= implode(' ', $words);
}

return $string;
}

 echo convert_number_to_words(17);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of above code what 1000111 posted:

```
     inner substring:
                 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th Seventeenth 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd Twentyfourth 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st', ' ' ,DAY('2016-02-17'))

         output:
                    First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th Seventeenth 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd Twentyfourth 

        outer substring:

                SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                        SUBSTRING_INDEX('First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th Seventeenth 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd Twentyfourth 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st', ' ' ,DAY('2016-02-17')),
                        ' ',
                        - 1
                    )

         output:

                "Seventeenth " if count is -1 
                "first" if count is 1
                "18th Seventeenth " if count is -2
                "first second" if count is 2

 input:

    SELECT
    CONCAT(
        MONTHNAME('2016-02-17'),
        ',',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX('First Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh Eighth Ninth Tenth 11th 12th 13th 14th 15th 16th Seventeenth 18th 19th 20th 21st 22nd 23rd TwentyFourth 25th 26th 27th 28th 29th 30th 31st', ' ' ,DAY('2016-02-17')),
            ' ',
            - 1
        ),
        ' ',
        YEAR ('2016-02-17')
    );

 output:
    Feb, Seventeenth 2016
```